# OpenGL per object materials

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, lighting, shading

I am writing my first 3D program in OpenGL 3.3 and I'm finding problems setting different materials for different objects. I managed to draw 3 spheres (vertices are stored in one VAO and then translated and drawn) and using uniforms I changed their appearance from the vertex shader. Now the problem is that the spheres should have different materials but I cannot figure out how to set different uniforms for each sphere. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: A material is somewhat equivalent to a shader program. You can bind different textures and uniforms and simply GlUseProgram() it when rendering your object. So before rendering each sphere bind the program and uniform your material properties (I.e textures etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gl_VertexID can be used . But best in this case is standandalone vbo I think.

https://rocketgit.com/user/bowler17/gl/source/tree/branch/wrench/blob/t.c

Comment: What do you mean with standalone vbo? Are you suggesting I should use one vbo for each sphere? And then I should store the material in the vbo?

Comment: smth like vec4 with mat coeficients. Like vbo with normals

Comment: Works like a charm!